# Why is IIS app pool stopping after long request?

Tags: asp.net-core-webapi, iis-10

I have created an API that makes calls to other APIs and returns a very long string (approximately 200mb).
Every time I make a request to it, it takes a long time to run then only responds with 4mb (exactly) of response and shut down the application pool.

I tried these solutions :

- Increase `executionTimeout` and `shutdownTimeout` to 01:00:00
- Setting `bufferingOn` to false and `bufferingLimit` to 1073741824
- Disable `Rapid-Fail Protection`

[image: Application pool advanced settings]

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <location path="." inheritInChildApplications="false">
    <system.webServer>
      <handlers>
        <add name="aspNetCore" path="*" verb="*" modules="AspNetCoreModuleV2" resourceType="Unspecified" />
      </handlers>
      <aspNetCore processPath=".\Program.exe" stdoutLogEnabled="false" stdoutLogFile=".\logs\stdout" hostingModel="inprocess" />
    </system.webServer>
  </location>
    <system.web>
        <httpRuntime executionTimeout="3600" shutdownTimeout="3600" />
    </system.web>
</configuration>
```

```
<location path="Internal Interfaces">
    <system.webServer>
        <asp bufferingOn="false">
            <limits bufferingLimit="1073741824" />
        </asp>
    </system.webServer>
</location>
```

Thanks,
Khalenn

Answer (score 0):

You can try this setting to increase the request Limits in iis.

**IIS Setting: Request Limits**:

```
<configuration>
  <system.webServer>
    <security>
      <requestFiltering>
        <requestLimits maxAllowedContentLength="2147483648" />
      </requestFiltering>
    </security>
  <system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

With the above maxAllowedContentLength, users can upload files that are 2 GB in size.

**Edit the request filtering feature settings and the request limits using IIS manager**:

1. Open IIS Manager.
2. Select the website that you want to configure.
3. Select Requests Filtering and open it by double-clicking the icon. The Request Filtering pane displays.
4. From the Actions pane on the right hand side of the screen click Edit Feature Settings... link. The Edit Request Filtering Settings window displays.
5. In the Request Limits section, enter the appropriate Maximum allowed content length (Bytes) and then click the OK button.
6. Restart IIS.

[image]

Comment: Hello @samwu, thanks for you answer.
I have tried raising the Maximum allowed content length parameter and it didn't work.
My problem is more on the response length that is cut to 4mb (then the application pool shuts down)